# How to add fading edge effect to Android Jetpack Compose Column or Row?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I need to implement LazyColumn with top fading edge effect. On Android I use [fade gradient for ListView or RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47483972/3124400), but couldn't find any solution for Jetpack Compose!

[image]

I tried to modify canvas:

```
@Composable
fun Screen() {
    Box(
        Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .background(color = Color.Yellow)
    ) {
        LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .drawWithContent {
                    val colors = listOf(Color.Transparent, Color.Black)
                    drawContent()
                    drawRect(
                        brush = Brush.verticalGradient(colors),
                        blendMode = BlendMode.DstIn
                    )
                }
        ) {
            itemsIndexed((1..1000).toList()) { item, index ->
                Text(
                    text = "Item $item: $index value",
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(12.dp),
                    color = Color.Red,
                    fontSize = 24.sp
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But have wrong result:

[image]

Comment: brush = Brush.verticalGradient(colors, endY = 500f)

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68686779/fading-edge-behaviour-in-jetpack-compose

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[In Compose 1.4.0-alpha02 CompositingStrategy was introduced](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/graphics/draw/modifiers#compositing-strategy). Which means it's not necessary to use the `.graphicsLayer { alpha = 0.99f }` hack anymore. Instead you can use `.graphicsLayer(compositingStrategy = CompositingStrategy.Offscreen)`.

Here's a customizable fading edge modifier:

```
fun Modifier.fadingEdge(brush: Brush) = this
    .graphicsLayer(compositingStrategy = CompositingStrategy.Offscreen)
    .drawWithContent {
        drawContent()
        drawRect(brush = brush, blendMode = BlendMode.DstIn)
    }
```

Some examples:

```
@Composable
fun FadingEdgeExamples() {
    Column(
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().background(Color.White)
    ) {

        val topFade = Brush.verticalGradient(0f to Color.Transparent, 0.3f to Color.Red)
        Box(modifier = Modifier.fadingEdge(topFade).background(Color.Blue).size(100.dp))

        val topBottomFade = Brush.verticalGradient(0f to Color.Transparent, 0.3f to Color.Red, 0.7f to Color.Red, 1f to Color.Transparent)
        Box(modifier = Modifier.fadingEdge(topBottomFade).background(Color.Blue).size(100.dp))

        val leftRightFade = Brush.horizontalGradient(0f to Color.Transparent, 0.1f to Color.Red, 0.9f to Color.Red, 1f to Color.Transparent)
        Box(modifier = Modifier.fadingEdge(leftRightFade).background(Color.Blue).size(100.dp))

        val radialFade = Brush.radialGradient(0f to Color.Red, 0.5f to Color.Transparent)
        Box(modifier = Modifier.fadingEdge(radialFade).background(Color.Blue).size(100.dp))

    }
}
```

Note: When specifying the gradient colors, Color.Transparent defines where the fade happens and any other color (in this case Color.Red, it doesn't matter which one you choose) defines the content.

Output:
[image: examples]

Comment: In my case, there are two elements in a `LazyRow`, and because of the size of the screen, the second element is cut down without any fading effect by default. And what I want to achieve is that when there is enough space for them to be displayed, no fading is provided (just on visual, not on code); when the space there is not enough, fading is provided. So I just wrap `LazyRow` into a `Box` with `fadingEdge` modifier you mentioned above, and add two `Spacer` into the head and the tail of the `LazyRow`. This just achieved my goal.

Answer (score 11):

Quick hack which fixes the issue: **add `.graphicsLayer { alpha = 0.99f }` to your modifer**

By default Jetpack Compose disables alpha compositing for performance reasons (as explained [here](https://blog.stylingandroid.com/compose-strikethru-animation/); see the "Custom Modifier" section). Without alpha compositing, blend modes which affect transparency (e.g. `DstIn`) don't have the desired effect. Currently the best workaround is to add `.graphicsLayer { alpha = 0.99F }` to the modifier on the `LazyColumn`; this forces Jetpack Compose to enable alpha compositing by making the `LazyColumn` imperceptibly transparent.

With this change, your code looks like this:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Screen() {
    Box(
        Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .background(color = Color.Yellow)
    ) {
        LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                // Workaround to enable alpha compositing
                .graphicsLayer { alpha = 0.99F }
                .drawWithContent {
                    val colors = listOf(Color.Transparent, Color.Black)
                    drawContent()
                    drawRect(
                        brush = Brush.verticalGradient(colors),
                        blendMode = BlendMode.DstIn
                    )
                }
        ) {
            itemsIndexed((1..1000).toList()) { item, index ->
                Text(
                    text = "Item $item: $index value",
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(12.dp),
                    color = Color.Red,
                    fontSize = 24.sp
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

which produces the correct result

[image]

Comment: In Compose 1.4.0-alpha02 CompositingStrategy was introduced. Which means it's not necessary to use the `.graphicsLayer { alpha = 0.99f }` hack anymore. Instead you can use `.graphicsLayer(compositingStrategy = CompositingStrategy.Offscreen)`. For more info, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76270310/10570201).

Answer (score 10):

What you could do is place a `Spacer` on top of the list, and draw a gradient on that Box. Make the Box small so only a small portion of the list has the overlay. Make the color the same as the background of the screen, and it will look like the content is fading.

```
val screenBackgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.background

    Box(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {

        LazyColumn(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            //your items
        }

        //Gradient overlay
        Spacer(
            Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(32.dp)
                .background(
                    brush = Brush.verticalGradient(
                        colors = listOf(
                            Color.Transparent,
                            screenBackgroundColor
                        )
                    )
                )
                //.align(Alignment) to control the position of the overlay
        )
    }
```

Here's how it would look like:

[image: screenshot]

However, this doesn't seem like quite what you asked for since it seems like you want the actual list content to fade out.
I don't know how you would apply an `alpha` to only a portion of a view. Perhaps try to dig into the `.alpha` sources to figure out.

Answer (score 3):

I optimised the @user3872620 solution. You have just to put this lines below your LazyColumn, VerticalPager.. and just adapt your offset / height, usually offset = height

```kotlin
Box(
    Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .offset(y= (-10).dp)
        .height(10.dp)
        .background(brush = Brush.verticalGradient(
            colors = listOf(
                Color.Transparent,
                MaterialTheme.colors.background
            )
        ))
)
```

You will got this render:
[There is the render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7TKV.png)

Answer (score 2):

Just a little nudge in the right direction. What this piece of code does is place a Box composable at the top of your LazyColumn with an alpha modifier for fading. You can make multiple of these Box composables in a Column again to create a smoother effect.

```
@Composable
fun FadingExample() {
    Box(
        Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .requiredHeight(500.dp)) {

        LazyColumn(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {

        }

        Box(
            Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(10.dp)
                .alpha(0.5f)
                .background(Color.Transparent)
                .align(Alignment.TopCenter)
        ) {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a very simple implementation of FadingEdgeLazyColumn using `AndroidView`. Place `AndroidView` with gradient background applied to the top and bottom of LazyColumn.

```kotlin
@Stable
object GradientDefaults {
    @Stable
    val Color = androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color.Black

    @Stable
    val Height = 30.dp
}

@Stable
sealed class Gradient {
    @Immutable
    data class Top(
        val color: Color = GradientDefaults.Color,
        val height: Dp = GradientDefaults.Height,
    ) : Gradient()

    @Immutable
    data class Bottom(
        val color: Color = GradientDefaults.Color,
        val height: Dp = GradientDefaults.Height,
    ) : Gradient()
}

@Composable
fun FadingEdgeLazyColumn(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    gradients: Set<Gradient> = setOf(Gradient.Top(), Gradient.Bottom()),
    contentGap: Dp = 0.dp,
    state: LazyListState = rememberLazyListState(),
    contentPadding: PaddingValues = PaddingValues(0.dp),
    reverseLayout: Boolean = false,
    verticalArrangement: Arrangement.Vertical =
        if (!reverseLayout) Arrangement.Top else Arrangement.Bottom,
    horizontalAlignment: Alignment.Horizontal = Alignment.Start,
    flingBehavior: FlingBehavior = ScrollableDefaults.flingBehavior(),
    userScrollEnabled: Boolean = true,
    content: LazyListScope.() -> Unit,
) {
    val topGradient =
        remember(gradients) { gradients.find { it is Gradient.Top } as? Gradient.Top }
    val bottomGradient =
        remember(gradients) { gradients.find { it is Gradient.Bottom } as? Gradient.Bottom }

    ConstraintLayout(modifier = modifier) {
        val (topGradientRef, lazyColumnRef, bottomGradientRef) = createRefs()

        GradientView(
            modifier = Modifier
                .constrainAs(topGradientRef) {
                    top.linkTo(parent.top)
                    width = Dimension.matchParent
                    height = Dimension.value(topGradient?.height ?: GradientDefaults.Height)
                }
                .zIndex(2f),
            colors = intArrayOf(
                (topGradient?.color ?: GradientDefaults.Color).toArgb(),
                Color.Transparent.toArgb()
            ),
            visible = topGradient != null
        )
        LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier
                .constrainAs(lazyColumnRef) {
                    top.linkTo(
                        anchor = topGradientRef.top,
                        margin = when (topGradient != null) {
                            true -> contentGap
                            else -> 0.dp
                        }
                    )
                    bottom.linkTo(
                        anchor = bottomGradientRef.bottom,
                        margin = when (bottomGradient != null) {
                            true -> contentGap
                            else -> 0.dp
                        }
                    )
                    width = Dimension.matchParent
                    height = Dimension.fillToConstraints
                }
                .zIndex(1f),
            state = state,
            contentPadding = contentPadding,
            reverseLayout = reverseLayout,
            verticalArrangement = verticalArrangement,
            horizontalAlignment = horizontalAlignment,
            flingBehavior = flingBehavior,
            userScrollEnabled = userScrollEnabled,
            content = content
        )
        GradientView(
            modifier = Modifier
                .constrainAs(bottomGradientRef) {
                    bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom)
                    width = Dimension.matchParent
                    height = Dimension.value(bottomGradient?.height ?: GradientDefaults.Height)
                }
                .zIndex(2f),
            colors = intArrayOf(
                Color.Transparent.toArgb(),
                (bottomGradient?.color ?: GradientDefaults.Color).toArgb(),
            ),
            visible = bottomGradient != null
        )
    }
}

@Composable
private fun GradientView(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    @Size(value = 2) colors: IntArray,
    visible: Boolean = true,
) {
    AndroidView(
        modifier = modifier,
        factory = { context ->
            val gradientBackground = GradientDrawable(
                GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM,
                colors
            ).apply {
                cornerRadius = 0f
            }
            View(context).apply {
                layoutParams = LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                )
                background = gradientBackground
                visibility = when (visible) {
                    true -> View.VISIBLE
                    else -> View.INVISIBLE
                }
            }
        }
    )
}
```