# Fading Edge behaviour in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a view that has a row of chips with a `fadingEdge`.

I'm reimplementing the page in Compose. But I'm not sure how to implement the `fadingEdge` behaviour in Compose.

I'd put a Spacer with the same length, and have a gradient as it's background, but that doesn't look like the same effect. The Android effect starts as invisible, then starts stretching to cover over the items as the view scrolls. That's not how a spacer would work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up creating my own [implementation](https://gist.github.com/dovahkiin98/85acb72ab0c4ddfc6b53413c955bcd10) of the `fadingEdge`

Comment: This is awesome. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I needed to implement **auto-scrolling text that fading at the edges**.

The solution from [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68708912/16593275) doesn't work for me because it doesn't suggest that the background can be a gradient or an image. In short, the accepted implementation is to overlay an additional layer, which is a gradient of the background and transparent colors.

Therefore, I wrote my own implementation that meets my requirements, in the end it looks like this:

[image: FadingScrollableText component preview]

`FadingScrollableText.kt`

```kotlin
package com.my.app

import android.content.res.Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES
import androidx.compose.animation.*
import androidx.compose.animation.core.tween
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.horizontalScroll
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.rememberScrollState
import androidx.compose.material3.*
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.saveable.rememberSaveable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.draw.drawWithCache
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.*
import androidx.compose.ui.layout.onSizeChanged
import androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle
import androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextAlign
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import com.my.app.theme.Theme

@ExperimentalAnimationApi
@Composable
fun FadingScrollableText(
    text: String,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    color: Color = Color.Unspecified,
    style: TextStyle = LocalTextStyle.current,
    enabled: Boolean = true,
) {
    val finalTextColor = color.takeOrElse {
        style.color.takeOrElse {
            LocalContentColor.current
        }
    }

    val scroll = rememberScrollState(0)

    var rowWidth by rememberSaveable {
        mutableStateOf(0)
    }

    var textWidth by rememberSaveable {
        mutableStateOf(0)
    }

    LaunchedEffect(rowWidth, textWidth, scroll.canScrollForward, scroll.isScrollInProgress) {
        if (rowWidth > 0 && textWidth > 0) {
            if (textWidth >= rowWidth) {
                if (scroll.canScrollForward && !scroll.isScrollInProgress) {
                    scroll.animateScrollTo(
                        value = textWidth,
                        animationSpec = tween(
                            durationMillis = 6666
                        )
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }

    LaunchedEffect(rowWidth, textWidth, scroll.canScrollBackward, scroll.isScrollInProgress) {
        if (rowWidth > 0 && textWidth > 0) {
            if (textWidth >= rowWidth) {
                if (scroll.canScrollBackward && !scroll.isScrollInProgress) {
                    scroll.animateScrollTo(
                        value = 0,
                        animationSpec = tween(
                            durationMillis = 666,
                            delayMillis = 999
                        )
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .onSizeChanged {
                rowWidth = it.width
            }
    ) {
        Row(
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .graphicsLayer(alpha = 0.99f)
                .drawWithCache {
                    val brush = Brush.horizontalGradient(
                        0.0f to Color.Transparent,
                        0.2f to finalTextColor,
                        0.8f to finalTextColor,
                        1.0f to Color.Transparent,
                    )
                    onDrawWithContent {
                        drawContent()
                        drawRect(brush, blendMode = BlendMode.SrcIn)
                    }
                }
        ) {
            AnimatedContent(
                targetState = text,
                transitionSpec = {
                    fadeIn() + slideInVertically() with fadeOut() + slideOutVertically(
                        targetOffsetY = { it / 2 }
                    )
                }
            ) { targetLabel ->
                Text(
                    text = targetLabel,
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Start,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .onSizeChanged {
                            textWidth = it.width
                        }
                        .horizontalScroll(
                            state = scroll,
                            enabled = enabled
                        )
                        .padding(horizontal = 16.dp),
                    maxLines = 1,
                    color = finalTextColor,
                    style = style
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true, uiMode = UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES)
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@ExperimentalAnimationApi
@Composable
fun FadingScrollableTextPreview() {
    Theme {
        Surface {
            FadingScrollableText(
                text = "Some long text ...",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(16.dp)
                    .width(128.dp)
                    .background(
                        brush = Brush.horizontalGradient(
                            colors = listOf(
                                MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primaryContainer,
                                MaterialTheme.colorScheme.tertiaryContainer
                            )
                        )
                    )
                    .padding(8.dp),
                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimaryContainer
            )
        }
    }
}
```

This implementation is independent of background and text color.

Additions and fixes are welcome.

***P.S.***

*Perhaps this is not a full-fledged answer to the question posed. But I feel the need to post it here, because when I tried to google the implementation I needed, this page was almost always one of the first in the search results.*