# How to implement this type of number picker in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

[Image Of Number Picker Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rveGs.png)

I have tried lazy list with fling behavior but it only selects first item I tried to search multiple resources but found no clue, I heard of scaling lazy list in wearable but there was no alternative for that on mobile that i could found. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved using HorizontalPager and adjusting the alpha based on the item from the center. In the example below i have the inital item centered and then you can scroll right.

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun NumberPicker(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    BoxWithConstraints(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
        val contentPadding = (maxWidth - 50.dp) / 2
        val offSet = maxWidth / 5
        val itemSpacing = offSet - 50.dp
        val pagerState = rememberPagerState(pageCount = {
            10
        })

        val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

        val mutableInteractionSource = remember {
            MutableInteractionSource()
        }

        CenterCircle(
            modifier = modifier
                .size(50.dp)
                .align(Alignment.Center),
            fillColor = Color.Magenta,
            strokeWidth = 2.dp
        )

        HorizontalPager(
            modifier = modifier,
            state = pagerState,
            flingBehavior = PagerDefaults.flingBehavior(
                state = pagerState,
                pagerSnapDistance = PagerSnapDistance.atMost(0)
            ),
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = contentPadding),
            pageSpacing = itemSpacing,
        ) { page ->
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(50.dp)
                    .graphicsLayer {
                        val pageOffset = ((pagerState.currentPage - page) + pagerState
                            .currentPageOffsetFraction).absoluteValue
                        // Set the item alpha based on the distance from the center
                        val percentFromCenter = 1.0f - (pageOffset / (5f / 2f))
                        val opacity = 0.25f + (percentFromCenter * 0.75f).coerceIn(0f, 1f)

                        alpha = opacity
                        clip = true
                    }
                    .clickable(
                        interactionSource = mutableInteractionSource,
                        indication = null,
                        enabled = true,
                    ) {
                        scope.launch {
                            pagerState.animateScrollToPage(page)
                        }
                    }) {
                Text(
                    text = "$page",
                    color = Color.Black,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(50.dp)
                        .wrapContentHeight(),
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can customize the color and font and stroke width as you wish along with the alpha of the items absed on how far it is from the center

[image]

Center circle is just a circle drawn on canvas

```
@Composable
fun CenterCircle(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    fillColor: Color,
    strokeWidth: Dp
) {
    Canvas(
        modifier = modifier
            .size(75.dp)
    ) {

        drawArc(
            color = fillColor,
            0f,
            360f,
            true,
            style = Stroke(strokeWidth.toPx(), cap = StrokeCap.Round),
            size = Size(size.width, size.height)
        )
    }
}
```

When scroll animation settles you can get the settle page or item as

```
    val context = LocalContext.current

    LaunchedEffect(pagerState) {
        // Collect from the a snapshotFlow reading the currentPage
        snapshotFlow { pagerState.settledPage }.collect { page ->
            Toast.makeText(context,"$page",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I can managed this far, may be you can craft something with these two answers. I used compoisitingStrategy of graphics layer which is mentioned in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76270310/17064732):

> In Compose 1.4.0-alpha02 CompositingStrategy was introduced. Which
> means it's not necessary to use the .graphicsLayer { alpha = 0.99f }
> hack anymore. Instead you can use .graphicsLayer(compositingStrategy =
> CompositingStrategy.Offscreen).

**This is the fading edge custom modifier:**

```kotlin
fun Modifier.fadingEdge(brush: Brush) = this
    .graphicsLayer(compositingStrategy = CompositingStrategy.Offscreen)
    .drawWithContent {
        drawContent()
        drawRect(brush = brush, blendMode = BlendMode.DstIn)
    }
```

**This is the text composable bordered when its in center:**

```
@Composable
fun BorderedText(lazyListState: LazyListState, index: Int) {

    val borderColor by remember {
        derivedStateOf {
            val layoutInfo = lazyListState.layoutInfo
            val visibleItemsInfo = layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo
            val itemInfo = visibleItemsInfo.firstOrNull { it.index == index }

            itemInfo?.let {

                val delta = it.size / 2 //use your custom logic
                val center = lazyListState.layoutInfo.viewportEndOffset / 2
                val childCenter = it.offset + it.size / 2
                val target = childCenter - center
                if (target in -delta..delta) return@derivedStateOf Red
            }
            Transparent
        }
    }


    Text(
        text = index.toString(),
        style = TextStyle(fontSize = 20.sp),
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(50.dp)
            .border(2.dp, borderColor, CircleShape)
            .wrapContentHeight(),
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center
    )
}
```

**and this is our main composable:**

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun FadingEdgeNumberPicker() {

    val lazyListState = rememberLazyListState()
    val snapBehavior = rememberSnapFlingBehavior(lazyListState = lazyListState)

    val leftRightFade = Brush.horizontalGradient(
        0f to Color.Transparent,
        0.5f to Color.Red,
        0.5f to Color.Red,
        1f to Color.Transparent
    )

    LazyRow(
        state = lazyListState,
        flingBehavior = snapBehavior,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fadingEdge(brush = leftRightFade)
            .fillMaxWidth(),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(2.dp)
    ) {
        items(100) {
            BorderedText(lazyListState = lazyListState, index = it)
        }
    }
}
```

as result you will get this:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help the first answer has already helped me anyways thanks for your efforts it's appreciated.